# Gregorian Calendar object to match dates inside ArrayList

Tags: java, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I am creating a gregorian calendar inside a method called filterBookings() which needs to create a gregorian calendar object inside it to match the dates which are inputted by the user (get selected item from 3 separate ComboBoxes called cmbYear,cmbMonth and cmbDay). The arrayList is called filteredBookings is currently is globally created. If the dates match the index of the matched booking it should be added to the arraylist.The inputs are already mentioned in the code. In the output panel it is saying : Unparseable Date. Can anyone help?I am new to this and do not have a background on this :(

```
 ArrayList <GregorianCalendar> filteredBookings = new ArrayList<>();
 public PhotoshootManager() throws ParseException {
     initComponents();
     filterBookings();
 }

 public void filterBookings(){   
     GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

     String getYear =(String) (cmbYear.getSelectedItem());
     String getMonth =(String) (cmbMonth.getSelectedItem());
     String getDay =(String) (cmbDay.getSelectedItem());

     DateFormat setCal = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

     try {
         Date date = setCal.parse(getDay+ "/" + getMonth +"/" + getYear);
     } catch (ParseException ex) {

         Logger.getLogger(PhotoshootManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
                 null, ex);
     }
 }
```

This is a school project, and unfortunatly we have to use the old `GregorianCalendar` class.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: @BasilBourque  Yeah i know that but this is a school project and unfortunatly we have to use it.

Comment: Too bad and frankly a bit scandalous: teaching and forcing you to use the bad and outdated tool when a good and current one is at hand. My sympathy.

Comment: If I get that correctly: Fill `Integer` objcets into your comboboxes, not strings. Then feed the unboxed selected values into either `LocalDate.of()` or `Calendar.set()`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Assuming the user selects combobox strings `2019`, `3` and `25`, your code parses nicely into `Mon Mar 25 00:00:00 CET 2019`. Could you edit the question and (1) give an example of strings the user chooses (2) quote the full error message, and (3) in your `catch` block also call `ex.getErrorOffset()` and print the return value for us?

Comment: Just checking: Are you trying to parse a date *before* the user has selected any items? Could the selected items (or some of them) be `null`?

Comment: first he choose the dates from the comboboxes then it needs to be parsed @OleV.V.

Answer (score 1):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

## `ZonedDateTime`

Specifically, the `GregorianCalendar` class is replaced by [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). This class represents a moment, a point on the timeline, as a date, a time-of-day, and a time zone.

But `ZonedDateTime` is not appropriate for scheduling future appointments. Instead, we must separate the date and time from the time zone when booking future appointments. More explanation below.

## `LocalDate`

Convert your string inputs for year, month, and day to numbers.

```
int y = Integer.parseInt( year ) ;
int m = Integer.parseInt( month ) ;
int d = Integer.parseInt( day ) ;
```

Instantiate a `LocalDate`. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( y , m , d ) ;
```

## `LocalDateTime`

Your `Booking` class should have [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) member variable. This class purposely lacks any concept of [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). We use this for future appointments because politicians around the world frequently change the offset of their respective time zone(s). Often, they do so with little or even no warning. For appointments such as “3 PM on January 23” we usually mean 3 PM by the clock on the wall per the time zone currently in force on that date, not as defined today. For example, if the government moves the clock by a half-hour, we do not want our appointment at 2:30, we still want 3:00 — a different moment than if the politicians had left the time zone definitions untouched.

## `ZoneId`

We also need to store the intended time zone with the appointment. The zone is applied to the `LocalDateTime` at runtime when we need a moment, a specific point on the timeline.

## `Booking` class

So your `Booking` class looks something like this.

```
public class Booking {
    String clientName ;
    LocalDateTime appointment ;
    ZoneId zoneId ;
}
```

To instantiate:

```
LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime( 2019 , 1 , 23 , 15 , 0 , 0 , 0 ) ; // 3 PM on Jan 23, 2019.
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
Booking booking = new Booking( "Alice" , ldt , z ) ;
```

Collect such instances.

```
List< Booking > bookings = new ArrayList<>() ;
bookings.add( booking ) ;
```

## Compare to filter

To filter those bookings by a certain date, loop the collected `Booking` objects, retrieve the `LocalDateTime` from each, extract the date-only value (a `LocalDate`), and compare to the target date.

```
LocalDate target = LocalDate.of( 2019 , Month.FEBRUARY , 1 ) ; // First of February.
List< Booking > filteredBookings = new ArrayList<>() ;
for( Booking booking : bookings ) {
    if( booking.appointment.toLocalDate().isEqual( target ) ) {
        filteredBookings.add( booking ) ; // Collect this `Booking` object whose date matches our target date.
    }
}
```

## `ZonedDateTime` revisited

When you need a specific moment, such as building a calendar system, or when recording history, apply the time zone (`ZoneId`) to the date-with-time (`LocalDateTime`) to get a moment (`ZonedDateTime`).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = booking.appointment.atZone( booking.zone ) ;
```

To see that moment in UTC, same point on the timeline but a different wall-clock time, extract an `Instant` object.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;  // Adjust from time zone to UTC.
```

Usually best to work with UTC rather than a zoned value for logging, database, storage, and data exchange.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your error most probably come from this line `Date date = setCal.parse(getDay+ "/" + getMonth +"/" + getYear);` Here you expect date in format `"dd/MM/yyyy"` but maybe the values that come as input are different. Please, check what you have for `getDay`, `getMonth`  and `getYear`.

P.S. After you find your error you need to make Date obejct to Calendar. You can do this:

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.setTime(date);
 filteredBookings.add(cal);
```

Good luck!

Comment: from the getdate and the others...the user has to choose the date from 3 separate combo boxes...so i dont how exactly this needs to be done. the get year has to get the year choosen from the user and also the same for the others ..after the date chosen needs to be converted in a gregorian calendar

Comment: So you need to debug and inspect the values inside your IDE (like Eclipse) while your program works. If you find this too complex then just add `System.out.println("Value for getDay: " + getDay);` after the line `String getDay =(String) (cmbDay.getSelectedItem());` and so on. Then execute the program again inside your IDE and in the console output you can check which values you will receive

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of

```
 String getYear =(String) (cmbYear.getSelectedItem());
 String getMonth =(String) (cmbMonth.getSelectedItem());
 String getDay =(String) (cmbDay.getSelectedItem());
```

Is null , also you put an invalid mounth or day java don't go in exception here an example :

```
        public static void filterBookings(){   
           String getYear ="20192525";
           String getMonth ="4444444444";
           String getDay ="1132632626";



            DateFormat setCal = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  

             try {
                 Date date = setCal.parse(getDay+ "/" + getMonth +"/" + getYear);
                 System.out.println(date);
             } catch (ParseException ex) {

              System.out.println("ko");
             }
           }
    }
```

output:

```
Thu Sep 19 00:00:00 CEST 35749996
```